# Opening camera with preview option at bottom in xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a requirement in my app where i have to open iphone camera from my app with preview option at bottom(shown in attached image) like how it is in iphone camera app.

Can someone please guide me on how to achieve this.

[image]

Thanks
Varun

Answer (score 0):

Create a `UIImagePickerController` from code, adjust its properties, add an overlay onto it, and with you controller, control whatever you want on that overlay : custom controls, overlaying images, etc.

That gives something like this :

```
self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
self.picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
self.picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
self.picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
self.picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

// Insert the overlay
self.overlay = [[OverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Overlay" bundle:nil];
self.overlay.pickerReference = self.picker;
self.picker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlay.view;
self.picker.delegate = self.overlay;

[self presentModalViewController:self.picker animated:NO];
```

`OverlayViewController` is the controller that you must write to control everything you add onto the overlay.

`pickerReference` is a property you can keep to send orders to the camera. For example, you could call the following from an IBAction coming from a UIButton placed onto the overlay :

```
[self.pickerReference takePicture];
```

you see this link for example https://github.com/anka/bw_examples